# Javascript: Dynamically added script can't find previously defined function in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-script-loading

I'm having what seems to be a really simple issue that I really can't find a solution for:

In my code I have a script loaded in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/viewdoc/index.js?v=1.33"></script>
```

In that specific script I declare the functions:

```
function addResizeListener(listener){
    //Attach the back button function to window resize event
    if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', listener); //Old browsers
    }
    else if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', listener, true); //New browsers
    }
}
```

and:

```
function removeResizeListener(listener){
    //Remove the listener for the back button
    if(window.detachEvent) {
        window.detachEvent('onresize', listener);
    }
    else if(window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', listener, true);
    }
}
```

then I load this file into the element with a **loaderdoc** id:

```
if ($('#loaderdoc').is(':empty')){
    $('#loaderdoc').load('../viewdoc/welcome.php');
}
```

I use the function addResizeListener to bind a function to the window resize event, this works perfectly, and the **index.js** script ends.

In the end of the loaded file **welcome.php** i added the line

```
<script src="../js/viewdoc/welcome.js"></script>
```

**welcome.js** is a script that uses the functions removeResizeListener and addResizeListener, but I get the error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: addResizeListener is not defined

Why is this? Wasn't the functions defined and loaded before the script was added to the document?

Sorry if this was answered before, I just couldn't really find it, or maybe I don't know he right way to search for it yet.

And thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you have a reference to "index.js" on welcome.php?

Comment: I believe this symptom indicates that `welcome.php` is finished loading before `index.js`. Look at your Network console and set breakpoints accordingly to verify.

Comment: It seems like it loaded after, at least looking through the waterfall on chrome network tab, though if it is async i wouldnt count on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` is async. Thus `welcome.js` will be executed, before the functions are defined. You have to use a callback. See https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Interesting, how would that look like? something like a $(document).ready(function(e) { //load stuff } function would work?

Comment: The  $(document).ready(function(e) { //load stuff } worked perfectly!